# Help with proving that this relation is antisymmetric

Tags: functions, relations

I was given a relation R in Z defined as xRy if $|x|<|y|$ or (|x|=|y| and x<0) or $x=y$. I need to prove that this relation is antisymmetric.

From what I understood, I can prove this by proving that if $x\ne y$ and xRy, then never yRx.
If $x \ne y$ and xRy, then |x|<|y| or |x|=|y| and x<0 (or x=y, which is not true since we assumed $x\ne y$). Then I would need to prove that yRx can't be true, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe easier to prove (and equivalent): if xRy and yRx, then $x = y$. You can typeset $\ne$ by ```\ne```.

Comment: Hint: since each of $xRy,\,yRx$ happens in one of three situations, one being $x=y$, you need only consider a $2\times 2$ table of alternatives, then show each implies either $x=y$ or a contradiction.

Comment: @J.G. so if i understood correctly, I need to prove that if |x|<|y| and |y|<|x|, then x=y and if |x|<|y| and |x|=|y|, then x=y etc?

Comment: That's one of four cells in the table, but it leads to a contradiction. In fact, you should find three of them do, while the last implies $x=y$.

Comment: @J.G. I must admit I’m a bit lost… what are the rest of the cells and how can I prove that they imply x=y or that they lead to a contradiction?

Comment: The rows are two cases for $xRy$, one for $|x|<|y|$, the other for $|x|=|y|\land x<0$. The rows are two analogous cases for $yRx$. Now try filling in the table.

Comment: @J.G. the only case where xRy and yRx imply x=y is when |x|=|y| and x<0 and |y|=|x| and y<0, correct?

Comment: The other cases lead to contradictions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139704/discussion-between-luna-and-j-g).